# Understanding ODBC SQL Grammar - Need Catalog Examples

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc

I've recently learned that ODBC has its own SQL grammar that eliminates SQL dialects, and thus makes all databases look "uniform".  However, there is almost a complete absence of meaningful online documentation or discussion about this.  Thus I don't have answers to questions like:

- What is an *example* ODBC SQL statement(s) that catalogs all tables in a DB?
- What is an *example* ODBC SQL statement that catalogs all columns in a table, or catalogs the primary key columns in a table?
- To expand on the prior two questions, to achieve the same query results, what is an *example* of native (e.g. T-SQL) versus ODBC SQL?
- How do I determine if the SQL I'm authoring is ODBC compliant?  Note: I'm usually using SSMS.

Here is the quote that originally introduced me to the existence of an ODBC-specific SQL grammar:

> In addition to a standard call-level interface, ODBC defines a standard SQL grammar. This grammar is based on the Open Group SQL CAE specification. [MS ODBC Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/the-odbc-solution?view=sql-server-ver15)

Elsewhere I found this quote:

> Therefore, there are really two choices of grammar to use: the SQL-92 grammar (and the ODBC escape sequences) and a DBMS-specific grammar. Of the two, only the SQL-92 grammar is interoperable, so all interoperable applications should use it. [MS docs 'choosing a SQL dialect'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/choosing-an-sql-grammar?view=sql-server-ver15)

I'd like to answer my own questions, and so I googled "SQL-92 query table catalog". The best I've found is [from this link](https://documentation.help/acdata/ac_8_con_05_6e2b.htm), which in turn offers an ODBC "Using Catalog Functions" link - which is broken.  I creatively found a way to locate the "[Using Catalog Functions](https://documentation.help/odbcsql/od_6_037_7alv.htm)" link myself, and found that it too is vague and provides no examples.

I'd really like to see actual examples, demonstrating true ODBC-compliant SQL catalog queries, and I've still not found anything.

## Update

I just spotted my first-ever [example code for fetching a catalog with ODBC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqltables-function?view=sql-server-ver15).  This has become very "Alice in Wonder Land" to discover the catalog functions, apparently, are not part of an alleged ODBC SQL grammar.  Rather, apparently(?), they are part of (required) SDK signatures.  Here is a C++ snippet from that link which demonstrates the `SQLTables` function.

```cpp
   // all catalogs query  
   printf( "A list of names of all catalogs\n" );  
   retCode = SQLTables( hstmt, (SQLCHAR*)SQL_ALL_CATALOGS, SQL_NTS, (SQLCHAR*)"", SQL_NTS, (SQLCHAR*)"", SQL_NTS, (SQLCHAR*)"", SQL_NTS );  
   for ( retCode = SQLFetch(hstmt) ;  MySQLSuccess(retCode) ; retCode = SQLFetch(hstmt) )  
      printCatalog( catalogResult );
```

At this point, I don't know if the above example represents the bulk of my answer - or if it is just a nuanced part of the answer.

Comment: I'd take a look at http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/doc/iodbc/wiki/iodbcWiki/WelcomeVisitors.

Comment: I can't remember any ODBC-compliant SQL catalog queries, ODBC progarmmers use the ODBC catalog _functions_, which can be found here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/odbc-api-reference?view=sql-server-ver15.

Comment: The iodbc.org link does not provide any SQL grammar examples.  Otherwise, the closest that the MS link gets to examples, unfortunately, is [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/odbc-function-summary?view=sql-server-ver15).  And examples or not, I still don't know how I can validate that I'm writing ODBC-compliant queries.

Comment: To write portable code, ODBC or other, standard SQL should be a good start, but you'll soon find that most products have their own dialects. Some useful links https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_compliance, https://developer.mimer.com/sql-2016-validator/, https://dbfiddle.uk/.

Comment: @jarlh It's actually the other way around.  I already knew that each RDBMS has its own dialect (e.g. T-SQL), and now I've discovered there is also an ODBC common dialect.  I'm attempting to learn more about the latter, not the former.

Comment: From what I remember, the XPG3 SQL syntax is based on the SQL-92 syntax (intermediate level?). Why restrict your SQL coding to that old standard? Especially since only a very few vendors implement it.